# Datastore API always returning "dsid: Missing Value" error

Tags: dropbox, datastore

I'm trying to follow the datastore API tutorial and this simple request (sent via Fiddler):

```
POST https://api.dropbox.com/1/datastores/get_or_create_datastore HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: api.dropbox.com
Content-Length: 12
Authorization:  Bearer [snipped]

dsid=default
```

always results in this error response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"error": {"dsid": "Missing value"}}
```

The access token was created from the developer app console, and my test app has full dropbox permissions.  Running the `list_datastores` API call succeeds and reports that I do have one datastore with a `dsid` of `default`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a header of `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-url-encoded`, since you're sending form-encoded parameters.

Comment: A great suggestion, but unfortunately it returns the same error regardless of the Content-Type header.

Comment: In that case, I can't reproduce the error. Can you try this via `curl` and send the output of `curl -v ...`?